# Arithmetic overflow error while converting varchar to decimal datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

I am trying to convert varchar(14) to Decimal(14,2).
My code is something like

```
Declare @varchar_variable varchar(14), @decimal_variable decimal(14,2)

Set @varchar_variable = '189'

Select @decimal_variable = Convert(Decimal(14,2),@varchar_variable)
```

I am only getting Arithmetic overflow error message when the value of @varchar_variable is large (like '10000000000189')

Why am I getting this error message for larger values ? Are values like 10000000000189 out of range for decimal datatype ? If yes, what is the range of decimal datatype in SQL.

Comment: Because `'10000000000189'` *is* too large... The largest value you can store in a `decimal(14,2)` is 999,999,999,999.99; your number (10,000,000,000,189) is about 100 times larger than that.

Comment: Hi @Ankit Aakash, decimal(14, 2) means that you expect numbers 14 digits long of wich two digits are reserved for the place after the decimal separator. So the largest number you expect is 999999999999,99  . Like you can see there is 12 digits in front of the decimal separator and 2 digitst after. The number causing you problems is 10000000000189,00and that number has 14 digits before and 2 digits after the decimal separator.

Comment: A `DECIMAL(27, 13)` is the smallest type that could hold all possible values in a `VARCHAR(14)`: 14 digits with no digit separator and 13 with (and no leading zero). Of course, you may not encounter values that need that much precision in practice, be sure to check -- declaring decimals with too much precision can lead to rounding problems later when they're involved in calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define Decimal(16,2) to convert varchar(14) to decimal. You can alternatively use Cast instead of Convert.

```
Declare @varchar_variable varchar(14), @decimal_variable decimal(16,2)

Set @varchar_variable = '10000000000189'


Select @decimal_variable = CAST(@varchar_variable AS DECIMAL(16,2))

-- Select @decimal_variable = Convert(Decimal(16,2),@varchar_variable)

SELECT @decimal_variable
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, `Decimal(14,2)` contains 14 digits in total.

Try increment your variable size;

```
Select Convert(Decimal(16,2),'10000000000189')
```